# New mobile UI template for chat scrolling problem

Tags: bug, chat, design, mobile-web

I just applied new SE chat template, template looks really awesome but I can't scroll.
I tried many browsers but nothing changed.

**Browsers I have tried:**

- Browser (default android 4.2.2 browser)
- CM browser
- Mozilla Firefox
- Chrome

There is bug with a menu button too, when I click it nothing happens.
It only changes style (toggle).

**Device:** Alcatel one touch pop c2
**OS:** Android 4.2.2 (build 01002)

Comment: Could you post one or two screenshots? That could be really helpful. Thanks!